# AJAX to PHP Image Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to upload multiple images from AJAX to PHP. Here's a run down of what I have so far.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input class="images" type="file">
</form>
```

There could be more than one input field if the user has multiple images to upload.

---

**Javascript**

```
var imageObject = GetAllFiles($('.images'));

function GetAllFiles(_selector)
{
     var newObject = {};

     for (var i = 0; i < $(_selector).length; i++)
     {
         var elem = $(_selector)[i];
         newObject[i] = $(elem).files;
     }

     return newObject;
 }

 $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
     var _data = JSON.stringify(imageObject);
     $.post('upload.php', { action: 'ImageUpload', data: _data }, function (e){
         alert(e);
     });
 )};
```

Send data via AJAX after conversion to JSON

---

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    switch($action)
    {
        case 'ImageUpload' : ImageUpload($_POST['data']); break;
    } 
}

function ImageUpload($jsonData)
{
    $images = json_decode($jsonData);

    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        $directory = "../images/maschine/";
        $target_file = $directory . basename($_FILES[$image])['name'];

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
        {
            echo('Success');
        } else 
        {
            echo('Failure');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the complete code, not just parts of it. While you're at it, you might want to include an actual question and let us know what it is you're having issues with and what you have tried.

Comment: Why would I show the complete code? It would just confuse people. I showed step by step all the code for the images.

Comment: I mean all the _relevant_ code. Like, what is `$('.images')`? Are you using `FormData` etc? We could guess, but that's kind of pointless.

Comment: You're not passing the `$image` to your `UploadImage()` function + you're missing a `;`

Comment: Do you have an error message, what is the problem?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please view it.

Comment: You're iterating through `$('.images')` while your file-input has the class `nm-bild`

Comment: My apologies, I am writing the code for a German. I have fixed it.

Comment: @LarsPeterson what does your developer console show and does php's error reporting throw anything back? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Sorry, the things you suggested were indeed right, but the were typos when I made the post.

Comment: @LarsPeterson you will need to use the @ symbol here just as I did for you here, followed by a member's name, followed by a space then your message to them. They may not know who you're addressing.

Comment: @Fred -ii- The console shows nothing. I am also not getting an alert like I should during the callback. The error must be the PHP.

Comment: You should copy/paste the _actual code_. Don't rewrite it for SO. That just adds more/other bugs/issues. We can't help you with code we don't see.

Comment: @LarsPeterson if it's a php issue, it could be a parse error, a path issue, a permissions issue or any one combined. Look at your (error) logs also if you have access to them. Are you running this off a hosted site or local? If local, are you using `http://localhost` or as `file:///`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am running on a MAMP local server. I have checked the error logs, nothing. Also the `foreach` loop in the PHP doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I also checked the `php.ini` file to make sure I had upload permissions.

Comment: @LarsPeterson well I am a bit baffled. The only thing I can see is that the probable multiple files you're trying to upload doesn't contain a `multiple` for the input. Try adding that; yet if you're only trying to allow/want to upload a single file, there's no need for the `foreach`. If you are wanting to allow multiples, look at example #3 in http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php where they have `$tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];` and `$name = basename($_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]);` using `[$key]` as the multi-dimensional array; that could be it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe my edit will help you solve it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Maybe my edit will help you solve it.

Comment: @LarsPeterson as shown in the answer below, `enctype='multipart/form-data'` is usually required to be added to the `<form>` and using a POST method. I've never really worked in-depth with what you're using, so I may not be of much more help, sorry. Btw, have you tried the answer given?

Answer (score -1):

Add id in the file input first, and remember the enctype='multipart/form-data' in form.

```
<input class="images" name="file[]" type="file" multiple>
```

after that in the script

```
<script>  
$('YoursubmitbuttonclassorId').click(function() {
var filedata = document.getElementsByName("file"),
        formdata = false;
if (window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData();
}
var i = 0, len = filedata.files.length, img, reader, file;

for (; i < len; i++) {
    file = filedata.files[i];

    if (window.FileReader) {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    if (formdata) {
        formdata.append("file", file);
    }
}
if (formdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/path to upload/",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(res) {

        },       
        error: function(res) {

         }       
         });
        }
  });
 </script>
```

In the php file

```
 <?php
  for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $ext = explode('.', basename( $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));
    $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext)-1]; 

     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file has been uploaded successfully <br />";
     } else{
         echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! <br 
     />";
     }
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer

Comment: I give here example for upload the multiple images.

Comment: Yes but there is literally no comment

Comment: So what type of comment you are want?

Comment: It's not for me, your post is supposed to answer the OP's question, not give him a bunch of code to read and understand on his own